# What is a good laptop for game development in 2021/2022? (Unity)

Tags: laptop, development, quiet-computing, game-development

I am a computer science student who has done game development for a decent time now, but I have been doing it on a Alienware M15 R2. It works pretty well still. The problem is I also use it for school work and for general browsing, but this laptop drains battery fast and get's extremely loud. (It's a gaming laptop with a 2070 in it)

Right now I am considering the MacBook Pro 14, Razer Blade 14 and XPS 15. They look real nice and preform well. The Mac does well on battery, is quiet, better keyboard than previous years. The Blade 14 and XPS have windows though. I don't like Mac OS but I wouldn't mind getting used to it and I don't spending the money if it means a better experience. If Unity runs better on this device than any other, then 100% I'll get it. But if there is a windows device that has similar performance, doesn't get that loud and good battery then I'll take that.

Any other recommendations besides these? Anything that has good battery life and performance? Any rumors for devices coming out in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asus RoG Strix G15 G513IE-HN004W is almost what you need, it performs good, has Windows (if needed, you can probably dualboot Linux), it has a dGPU, which is useful for testing, it has an 8-core Ryzen CPU, which is good to reduce compile times. The only less good thing is it only goes 3-5 hours on battery, which is less than the 3 other laptops you mentioned...

Comment: Is the low battery life only under a big load? If I have google chrome or visual studio open for class will it drain fast too?

Comment: Probably not, but it won't last the entire day. My advice is to take a charger with you to school when you go for this laptop. (I also need that with my hp probook if I have more than 4 hours of lessons)